# Нужно тире или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Как написать правильно: "Язык произведения ─ русский" или "Язык произведения: русский"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это предложение из обычного текста, то используйте тире. Если у вас форма для заполнения данных, то может стоять двоеточие. Например.

Название произведения: "Кое-что кое о чем"
Автор произведения: И. И. Иванов
Язык произведения: русский
Год издания: 2018